# NSMutableDictionary initialization in non-ARC app

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I don't know if I'm completely brainfarting today, or what.  But basically I'm trying to initialize a NSMutableDictionary to be used.  I have it as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *baseViewDictionary;
```

in the .m file:

```
@synthesize baseViewDictionary;



// in the init method:
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    self.baseViewDictionary = tempDict;
    [self.baseViewDictionary setObject:@"test" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]];
    [tempDict release];
```

I thought this was a pattern to be used to initialize a NSMutableDictionary.  Unfortunately, my self.baseViewDictionary never gets set.  My tempDict has 1 key/value pair I see in the debugger, but my self.baseViewDictionary has 0x0000000.  So it's like

```
self.baseViewDictionary = tempDict;
```

never gets run.  When I step into that line of code, it jumps to the @synthesize baseViewDictoinary, then returns back to the `self.baseViewDictionary=tempDict` line.

Here's the picture of the debugger after `setObject@"test"` gets run.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is correct.
The initialization is done right, no memory leak as you release the dictionary after the assignation to the property, which retains it.

Are your sure your `init` method is correct?
I mean, calling `self = [ super init ]` (not `==`), doing your stuff after this, and returning `self`?

It may seem obvious, but as your instance variable seems to be `nil`, `self` may be `nil` also...

```
- ( id )init
{
    if( ( self = [ super init ] ) )
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * tempDict = [ [ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] initWithCapacity: 0 ];
        self.baseViewDictionary        = tempDict;

        [ self.baseViewDictionary setObject: @"test" forKey: [ NSNumber numberWithInteger: 0 ] ];
        [ tempDict release ];

        NSLog( @"%@", self.baseViewDictionary );
    }

    return self;
}
```